# does the lastest .Net 6 (SDK 6.0.418) support tls13 for linux-x64?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, .net-core, openssl, dotnet-httpclient

does the latest .Net 6 (SDK 6.0.418) support tls13 for linux-x64 ?

I have specified the handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls13.

But according to the wireshark, it still using Tls12 !

```
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls13;

        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (HttpRequestMessage message, X509Certificate2? certificate, X509Chain? chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) => return true;};
        var client = new HttpClient(handler); 
        var result = client.GetAsync("https://127.0.0.1:3030/").Result;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```